# How to run apps in the background using pm2 from a nodejs script?

Tags: node.js, shell, pm2

I am trying to create an app that allows me to create demos of my other apps and run them on subdomain. Now everything works when I run my app through `node server.js` command, but when I run it in the background using `pm2 start server.js`, The following script doesnt work. When I log into my droplet using SSH, and run `pm2 status`, the demo app's start script is not on the list. What should I do?

```
const runInitialServerConfigurationNodejs = async (subdomain, port) => {
    await shellPromise(`cp /var/www/${subdomain}_app/server/.env.example /var/www/${subdomain}_app/.env`);
    await shellPromise(`cd /var/www/${subdomain}_app/server && yarn`);
    await shellPromise(`mv /var/www/${subdomain}_app/server/server.js /var/www/${subdomain}_app/server/${subdomain}.js`);
    await shellPromise(`echo "APP_ENV=production" >> /var/www/${subdomain}_app/server/.env`);
    await shellPromise(`echo "MONGODB_KEY=mongodb://localhost:27017/${subdomain}_db" >> /var/www/${subdomain}_app/server/.env`);
    await shellPromise(`echo "NODE_PORT=${port}" >> /var/www/${subdomain}_app/server/.env`);
    await shellPromise(`cd /var/www/${subdomain}_app/server && pm2 start ${subdomain}.js && pm2 save && pm2 set pm2:autodump true`); // doesnt work here

}
```

Comment: What is the implementation of `shellPromise`?

Comment: Did you checked output of ‘pm2 logs’ or log file?

Comment: guys i figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Somehow pm2 does not work for my implementation. However i managed to get it working using the forever module.